# How should I say about time figuratively returning time?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrases, present-simple

I have and idea which I can't turn into a simple phrase that would efficiently transfer it. The idea is that, for each hour you (spend, or bill) today, you have to both pay yourself in the past (literally, back pay for your education or experience) and in future (cover risks). The sentence is

> One hour today should return you one hour from a year back in the past and back one hour in future.

How can this phrase be improved, made more concise, clear, and more appropriate to modern language?

Comment: Your intro paragraph says it much better than your attempted phrasing, which is totally confusing   Alas, some things are just not reasily condensable into a pithy adage.  If this one is, it would probably involve banking or insurance metaphors (loan, mortgage, amortize, investment, nest egg, premium, annuitize, sinking fund, coverage, indemnify, risk, hazard. . )

Answer (score 2):

Every hour you spend today should justify an hour spent in the past and save an hour from being spent in the future.